# Encrypting an access database

Tags: database, encryption

I have MS Access database which is password protected, i want to encryption with 128-bit encryption.

Any inputs?

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Comment: Post on superuser.com perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on how to do that: [Access Passwords and Encryption](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3752701/Secure-Microsoft-Access-Passwords-and-Encryption-in-Access-2007.htm)

Comment: Man, you beat me to it.  You had the same article I was going to link to.  +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks John & everyone, i will view the link.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0 from the link, but when i test the DB i don't see Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0 in the notepad. Any inputs?

I have an access 2007 database, after which i went into registry and created the steps as mentioned by the link.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3752701/Secure-Microsoft-Access-Passwords-and-Encryption-in-Access-2007.htm